# Help forming an aircraft cockpit

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

Hello,

I am trying to extend the lines on the body of the aircraft I am working on, see photo below.

I have used a combo of both scale and moving by the z axis so far, but I am unsure how to apply the lines of the model so they overlap the top line of the cockpit, having tried so far, it causes the bottom lines to bulge out over the bottom of the plane which I have already set, as seen in the pic.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably go about it like this:

[image]

And I'd likely keep the cockpit cover itself separate:

[image]